# Trocar TD da tabela de acordo com valor recebido

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso que o background da minha TD altere de acordo com o valor que ela recebe do ListView vindo de uma consulta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 

$(function () {                     

    var texto = $("#ListaSchedulesRdc td:nth-child(4)").text();

    var resultado = (texto);

    //alert(resultado);


    for (resultado in "#ListaSchedulesRdc") {


        if (resultado > 1) {

            $("#ListaSchedulesRdc td:nth-child(4)").css("background-image", "url(../Imagens/alerta-vermelho.png)", "background-repeat: no-repeat;", "class='alerta-vermelho'");
        }

        if (resultado = 1) {

            $("#ListaSchedulesRdc td:nth-child(4)").css("background-image", "url(../Imagens/alerta-amarelo.png)", "background-repeat: no-repeat;", "class='alerta-amarelo'");
        }

        if (resultado = 0) {

            $("#ListaSchedulesRdc td:nth-child(4)").css("background-image", "url(../Imagens/alerta-verde.png)", "background-repeat: no-repeat;", "class='alerta-verde'");
        }

    }

    });


 <asp:ListView ID="ListaSchedulesRdc" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1"  ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" >  

          <LayoutTemplate>  



            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <table border ="1" ID="ListaSchedulesRdc">  
                <tr id="ListaSchedulesRdcTr">  
                    <th>Nome              </th>  
                    <th>Ultima Rodada     </th>  
                    <th>Proxima Rodada    </th>  
                    <th>Ultimo Resultado  </th>  
                    <th>Quantidade Erros  </th>  
                    <th>Estado            </th>  
                </tr>  
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>  

            </table>  



        </LayoutTemplate>  
        <GroupTemplate>  
            <tr>  
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>  
            </tr>  
        </GroupTemplate>  



        <ItemTemplate>  


            <td><%# Eval("NomeTask")            %> </td>  
            <td><%# Eval("UltimaRodadaTask")   %> </td>  
            <td><%# Eval("ProximaRodadtaTask") %> </td>  
            <td id="ListaSchedulesRdcTd"><%# Eval("ResultadoTask")      %> </td>
            <td><%# Eval("ErrosTask")          %> </td>
            <td><%# Eval("EstadoTask")          %> </td>
        </ItemTemplate>  
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Na coluna estado?

Comment: Leandro, na coluna Ultimo Resultado, assim como na minha imagem que está amarelo, mas deveria estar de acordo com os If's do JavaScript;

Comment: ah, você quer fazer por js, poderia colocar diretamente no seu ItemTemplate  e  já renderizar com o resultado esperado, posta junto a sua pergunta o html da tabela renderizada também, só a imagem não ajuda tanto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está pegando o valor errado em:

```
var texto = $("#ListaSchedulesRdc td:nth-child(4)").text();
```

Desta forma, está retornando os valores da coluna inteira.

Além de que seu código possui muitos problemas, como operadores de comparação errados nos `ifs`.

Você pode fazer um *loop* percorrendo todas as linhas pegando o valor de cada quarta célula `td` e aplicar os `backgrounds` que deseja de acordo com o valor de cada uma.

Veja funcionando, como exemplo, abaixo:

```js
$('#ListaSchedulesRdc tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function(e,v){

   var resultado = $(v).text();

   if (resultado > 0) {
      $(this).css("background", "blue");
   }

   if (resultado == 1) {
      $(this).css("background", "red");
   }

   if (resultado == 0) {
      $(this).css("background", "yellow");
   }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="#ddd" id="ListaSchedulesRdc">
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         20
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         30
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         0
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Meu amigo, não tenho palavras para lhe agradecer.

Precisei fazer algumas adaptações e funcionou.

Não estava conseguindo fazer o 'ForEach' no JS e confundi alguns operadores de comparação.

Muito, muito obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]